# Save files in folders instead of separate files/customize pdf saving directory in TeXStudio

Tags: texstudio, mac

I use TeXStudio on Mac OS, and one thing I've always wanted to do is to save my files in folders instead of  separate files. For now it saves stuff like this:

[image]

But I want to combine the files for one document into one single folder, so that I don't have those auxiliary files flooding my finder. How can I save files such that the folder is created automatically with the files in them? Please note that I'm new to TeX, so I'm not familiar at all with macros and stuff. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `*tex` binaries accept the command line option `--output-directory <your output dir>`. But then, *everything* is written there including the typeset document (in DVI or PDF format). However, you could create another directory where you place links that point to your desired output file, e. g. the PDF. The method of creating file links depends on the OS you are on.

Comment: Where do I type that command line option?

Comment: Somewhere in the Preferences of texstudio. I don't use it myself, so I don't know where exactly. Also, `<your output dir>` must exist already. The simplest would be to just create an output directory manually and create the links to the PDF at it its regular location, *without* using `--output-directory ...`.

Comment: How do I create an output directory manually?

Comment: In the file explorer or in a terminal?

Comment: In my finder. This is Mac

Comment: I now know how to output the pdf to a specific location, can you please help me with the folder? Thanks a lot!

Comment: In your terminal, type `mkdir yourFolderName`.